# Usefulness of Thread Local Storage

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi

I don't understand why Microsoft decided to implement TLS (Thread Local Storage) in Windows. Isn't it possible to do something equivalent just by using GetCurrentThreadId()?

I think it takes more time to learn how TLS works than to implement your own version.

So why bother?

Comment: No, using TLS and using `GetCurrentThreadId()` are  nowhere near the same thing. It takes much more time to learn how TLS works because it's complex, and if you can't figure out what it does in the first place you're going to have a very difficult (if not impossible) time implementing your own version. Your own version would not have the OS managing things, which is a large part of the complexity you don't even see happening behind the scenes.

Comment: You can certainly replicate TLS with a dictionary keyed off the thread ID, as you suggest. I suppose MS added TLS because they implemented it very efficiently using the TEB. It's more convenient and efficient for you to use the system api.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It's just that I was expecting something more from TLS. It's not transparent enough. One has to allocate an index and then access the slots through Windows API. That's not very clean, IMHO.

Comment: You're close to the metal. Don't expect too many frills down there.

Comment: You know you can use [__declspec(thread)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w1sdazb.aspx) to get most of the work done for you?

Comment: No, I didn't know that. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Some compilers use `__thread` instead of `__declspec(thread)`.  Either way, the compiler+RTL manage the TLS API calls for you so you don't have to make them manually.  Just declare a variable as `__thread` or `__declspec(thread)` and use it like any other variable, knowing it is actually using TLS internally.